# Unable to run jQuery Masonry in a Sencha Touch 2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch-2, jquery-masonry

In my ST2 app I have on **index.html**

```
<script id="jquery" type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script id="masonry" type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/masonry-2.1.5.js"></script>
```

as well as

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('.x-list-container');            
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){                 
        $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.x-list-item',
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

My front page on the app is a **list** so it wraps elements as such

```
<div class="x-list-container">
    <div class="x-list-item"></div> // 'x-list-item' is the block I want to float
    <div class="x-list-item"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

However once everything is loaded and I inspect `.x-list-item` there is no `style` positioning the `div`. I am experience with Masonry on regular web app but can;t make it work here.

It's like Masonry isn't running at all.

It is being loaded (checked on the network tab) and jQuery is being loaded (on network tab and tested using `if (jQuery) {alert('hey there');`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha touch will not suport mixing Jquery for an application.

[Reason from forum's sencha moderator](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198792-Problem-wi-h-ST2-and-JQuery-Answered)

Comment: That's odd. I use both jQuery (I need it to use Soundcloud's player) and ST2 in an app and everything is working just fine.

Comment: Can you show me an example because I've tried 1 time before when include my jquery library in index.html. The only 1 function I can run from that time is alert hi and nothing else further.

Comment: that interesting - @TDeBailleul, is my setup OK? Do you have any suggestions on how you implemented it?

Comment: one point that should be made is somewhat semantic - 'not support' vs 'incompatible' -- still not sure which one is true, but there's enough evidence showing that it is possible to use jQuery w/ Sencha - and also that it's asking for trouble